# First login to Domain Account outside network

Tags: active-directory, windows-sbs-2008

I recently sent a new laptop to our branch outside the Country.
I set it up and tested it with a LOCAL "ROOT_ADMIN" account (a standard for our company).  I set him up as a local administrator from Windows SBS server 2008, but did not login with his credentials here in the USA.

When he tries to logon with his DOMAIN account he gets the error:
*"There are currently no logon servers available to service the logon request"*

He tested his internet with an ethernet cable, but when he plugs it into the new computer, it still can not find the logon server.

Does anyone have an idea on how he can login for the first time on his new machine?

Comment: wtf so many things wrong, not enough time to explain.

Comment: How did you set it up if you never logged on as the user even once? He's still got a whole lot of setting up to do when he gets it. Even if the user could log on, I would expect a laptop in that situation to lead to a lot of help requests from the user (unless he is very tech-savvy).

Comment: and a sh!t load of virus to boot.

Comment: were you just expecting cached creds to cover this or what?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If he's doing this from his home network, he would need to be VPNed into your network in order to contact the Domain Controller to authenticate.

In other words unless your Domain Controller was Internet facing, he would need to be on your network to get this to work.

Comment: My next thought was to have him set up a bridge connection on his existing machine and plug into the Ethernet that way.
The bridged machine would be VPN'd of course.

Comment: And please god don't put your DC onto the internet.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a vpn at your main site that the user can vpn into ?

Perhaps you could remote control the laptop via teamviewer or join.me and vpn them in from a local account

[For example](http://community.spiceworks.com/how_to/show/1382-joining-a-remote-computer-to-a-windows-domain) heres someone with a similar issue

You could also setup a vpn connection and allow it to be connected prior to the logon process.

[For example](http://htipe.wordpress.com/2010/02/11/connect-to-vpn-before-logging-in-to-windows/) heres someone who walks you through that

Of course for any of that to work though the remote user would have to be able to login to a local account first. Are you not able / willing to give him the local account password?

Comment: The laptop does not have teamviewer, or the VPN settings set up on it.
He can not login.

Comment: No, unfortunately I can't give him the admin credentials.
If he was connected to the network, I could remote login.  I will follow your links, thanks!